# Accessing package in java

Tags: java, oop, class, package

I have a package structure in Java and it should be accessible as shown below.

[image]

How to make Underlying package classes accessible to only Middle package? The TestApp should directly communicate with Interface package only. The TestApp should not get any information about Underlying and Middle package classes. How to do it? Please help

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Is it because you don't trust the developer of the TestApp? If you can only use the interfaces how do you every make use of the "Middle package"?

Comment: Would this Help? [Access Modifiers In Java](http://javapapers.com/core-java/access-modifiers-in-java-explain/)

Comment: Middle package methods should be called from Interface package

Comment: So I assume the interface code has more than just interfaces. ;) While it might be nice to be able to do this, you haven't said why its needed, there may be another way to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put TestApp and Interface in the same package. Then Interface must inherit Middle that use **protected** methods. Then Middle is in the same Package of Underlying that uses **package protected** methods.

It does what you want, but honestly, I see no sense of doing that. And it supposes that "Interface Package" is not a Java Interface...

[Ceylon Language](http://ceylon-lang.org/documentation/introduction/) has probably a better notion of Unit Of Code and Modules, but Java 6,7 & 8 languages are not ready to really hide things to other programmers.

Comment: Underlying, Middle and Interface layer forms a jar. So cudn't put TestApp and Interface in one package

Comment: Yes you can. When jar is unpacked in the JVM, it's a directory like others. You put your new TestApp with the same name of package and that's it. Honestly, if it's a client need, just tells them it's not working that way. You can use your code to hide Http request, but not a JVM to hide someone else code.

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible.
You can set package access to classes, but you will face difficulties calling them from other packages. That means that essentially access from middle package to underlying package is the same as access from TestApp to underlying package.
UPD: I saw the answer about inheritance, but it does not solve problem completely - you can inherit from underlying package in TestApp, nothing stops you from it.
UPD2: By the way, you requirements remind me of `friend` keyword in C++. It does not exist in Java.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to use a "friend" system in Java to specify more granular access to package members.  If you make something visible outside of a package, *anything* outside of that package can access it.

You could use a common package for the TestApp and Interface Package packages, but this isn't really semantically correct - you'd be mixing clients with interfaces.

If you want to enforce modularity, [OSGi](http://www.osgi.org/Main/HomePage) allows you to mark certain packages within a unit as "internal" - these won't be exposed ("wired") to clients at all.